# Как удалить локальную ветку, которая была создана из другой ветки?

Tags: git, git-branch

Я хотела создать новую ветку с мастера в IntelliJ IDEA, но вместо этого случайно создала ветку с другой ветки (homework-6)
Подскажите, как удалить ненужную ветку, в данном случае "hm6"?
Возможно тут были похожие вопросы, но не хочу усугублять ситуацию неправильными действиями [image: local branches]

Comment: пробовали кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши по названию ветки?

Comment: @KoVadim, высвечивает только Rename, Push

Comment: Сначала надо Checkout на другую, а потом появится Delete

Comment: @mrEvgenX, cпасибо, помогло. Можете добавить ваш комментарий как ответ,  я помечу его как "верный"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда новая ветка создается, в интерфейсе IntelliJ Idea в окошке для задания имени ветки есть переключатель "Checkout branch", из-за которого вновь созданная ветка становится активной. По-умолчанию он включен.

В git нельзя удалить ветку, на которой находишься.

Сначала надо Checkout на другую, а потом в интерфейсе появится Delete - то, что нужно.